# Excel VBA: how to cut multiple rows and paste in a new file and save?

Tags: excel, paste, cut, vba

I have daily repetive tasks that need a VBA to help me out.

I have a file which is updated daily, the excel file contains like:

First Name|Last Name|Email| Password
John| Lee | Johnlee#hotmail.com | blabla
......

So here are my tasks, when a client ask for like 100 accounts, I cut 100 accounts starting ROW 2 and open a new excel file and paste those accounts (100 rows) from ROW 2 in that new file, and then I COPY the first row  of the original file and paste that in the first row of the new file.

And then save the new file into the same folder.

And then save the original file.

I am thinking of putting a form in the file, one button and two text controls. One text control for inputting the number of rows which need to be cut and pasted each time, other text control for inputting username of the client, which will be used in the file name of the new file. I need the new file save in the name of "Number_username.xls".

I am very new to VBA and need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You always have the possibility to record macro. Record macro, do manually what what you want to program with VBA, stop macro recording and look inside the recorded macro.